# Why does my game keep on freezing when the player collides with the enemy in pygame

Tags: pygame

My game is basically space invaders but with tanks. I already put in all of the important bits like moving and firing the bullets and stuff but whenever the player tank is within a small distance from an enemy tank the game freezes, and the same happens with the bullets when I fire them, sometimes it randomly works but that's very rare.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import random


WIDTH=600
HEIGHT=600

FPS = 60
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (48, 69, 48) 
pygame.init()
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player_img = pygame.image.load('transparentplayer.png')
player = player_img.get_rect()
player.centerx = WIDTH // 2
player.bottom = HEIGHT - 50
 
enemy_img = pygame.image.load('transparent.png')
enemies = []
for i in range(3):
    enemy = enemy_img.get_rect()
    enemy.x = random.randint(0, WIDTH - 103)
    enemy.y = -50
    enemies.append(enemy)
 
bullet_img = pygame.image.load('transparentbullet.png')
bullets = []
 
direction = 'none'
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                direction = 'left'
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                direction = 'right'
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                direction = 'up'
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                direction = 'down'
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullet = bullet_img.get_rect()
                bullet.centerx = player.centerx
                bullet.y = player.top
                bullets.append(bullet)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key != pygame.K_SPACE:
            direction = 'none'
 
    screen.fill(GREEN)
 
    if direction == 'left':
        if player.x > 0:
            player.x -= 4
    if direction == 'right':
        if player.right < WIDTH:
            player.x += 4
    if direction == 'up':
        if player.y > 0:
            player.y -= 4
    if direction == 'down':
        if player.bottom < HEIGHT:
            player.y += 4
 
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.y += 3
        if enemy.top > HEIGHT:
            enemy.y = -70
            enemy.x = random.randint(0, WIDTH - 103)
 
    for enemy in enemies:
        screen.blit(enemy_img, (enemy.x, enemy.y))
 
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.y -= 3
 
    for bullet in bullets:
        screen.blit(bullet_img, (bullet.x, bullet.y))
 
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(bullets)):
        if bullets[i].y < 0:
            temp.append(i)
 
    temp.sort(reverse=True)
    for i in temp:
        del bullets[i]
 
    temp1 = []
    temp2 = []
    for i in range(len(bullets)):
        for j in range(len(enemies)):
            if bullets[i].colliderect(enemies[j]):
                temp1.append(i)
                temp2.append(j)
                temp1.sort(reverse=True)
                temp2.sort(reverse=True)
                
                
    for i in temp1:
        del bullets[i]
    for i in temp2:
        del enemies[i]
 
    for enemy in enemies:
        if player.colliderect(enemy):
            pygame.image.load("gameover.PNG")
            running = False
            
 
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        del temp[0]
    for i in range(len(temp1)):
        del temp1[0]
    for i in range(len(temp2)):
        del temp2[0]
 
    screen.blit(player_img, (player.x, player.y))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: When it freezes, does it stay frozen, does it crash, or does it recover? If you press Ctrl-c to interrupt the game when it's frozen, does it give you a line number of where the code was when it was interrupted? Any debugging information you can give will help people aid you with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking your code it looks like your game is supposed to end when you collide with an enemy. The only problem is only that you are not displaying the gameover image properly.
Try to replace this:

```
for enemy in enemies:
    if player.colliderect(enemy):
        pygame.image.load("gameover.PNG")
        running = False
```

with this:

```
for enemy in enemies:
    if player.colliderect(enemy):
        gameover = pygame.image.load("gameover.png")
        screen.blit(gameover,(WIDTH/2 - gameover.get_width()/2, HEIGHT/2 - gameover.get_height()/2))
        running = False
```

Also, I suggest you to load the gameover image before the game loop starts